# the usage of "to"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Re: [Englishtown, lesson 20](http://www.englishtown.com/community/channels/lesson2.aspx?ptn=memb&hash=bGVzc29uX2lkPTYzNiZ0YWI9MSZwdG49bm9uZSZzaWQ9MTk4MDE1NTImbGlkPTYzNiZlZD0yMDE0LTEwLTE2VDE3JTNhMzAlM2EwMCZjdHI9dWsmbG5nPWVuJmNjPSZldGFnPUUxMTM4ODBfbWVtYiZlZXZlcj000&etag=E113880_memb&eever=4)

He sees me, gets out of the truck, walks over to my car and tells me to, oh, what was it?

in the above context the meaning and usage of "to" is not clear for me. it looks unnecessary. am I right or not?

Comment: after reading the answer, I can understand the meaning of the sentence. I mean now I understand "what was it?" is not what "he" has told.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb *tell* can take an indefinite object (here *me*) and a *to-infinitive* as an object. Here the writer wants to use a to-infinitive. But instead of using a complete to-infinitive, the writer writes only the **to** part of the to-infinitive to represent that the speaker has forgotten what he was actually told.

Example:

> He sees me, gets out of the truck, walks over to my car and tells me ***to-infinitive***.

You could put just about any to-infinitive verb as an object of tell in this sentence.

For example:

He tells me **to** *jump*, *run*, *fish*, *scream*, *lie*, *relax*, *be calm*, *hurry up*, etc.

The purpose of **not** completing the to-infinitive is to reinforce the notion that the speaker has forgotten what *he*  (the subject of the sentence) told the speaker to do/say/feel, etc

The incomplete infinitive is successful in getting the idea of forgetting across to the reader. For this reason, the *to* is not extra.